# How to Delete in a many to many relationship?

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, many-to-many, cascading-deletes, nhibernate-cascade

I have a many to many relationship:

> Product has many Categories and Category has Many Products.

Say I have

```
Shopping Category  
Food Category

Product A - Shopping Category, Food Category  
Product B - Shopping Category
```

Now I delete `Shopping Category`. I want the `Product A` reference to be removed from `Shopping Category` and I want `Product B` to be removed completely.

I would end up with:

```
Product A - Food Category.
```

How do I do this in nhibernate (I am using fluent nhibernate).

I tried to use Cascade `DeleteOrphan` and `AllDeleteOrphan` but when I do that and delete Shopping both Product A and B get deleted.

```
public class CategoryMapping : ClassMap<Category>
{
    public CategoryMapping()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.GuidComb();

        Map(x => x.Name).Not.Nullable().NvarcharWithMaxSize();
        HasManyToMany(x => x.Products).Cascade.DeleteOrphan();
    }
}


public class ProductMapping : ClassMap<Product>
{
    public ProductMapping()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.GuidComb();
        Map(x => x.Name).Not.Nullable().NvarcharWithMaxSize();
        HasManyToMany(x => x.Categories);
    }
}

  unitOfWork.BeginTransaction();
  Category category =session.Load<Category>(id);
  session.Delete(category);
  unitOfWork.Commit();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this can be handled by mapping with existing data structure. I think you would need to write some manual code (*) or change data structure.

(*) Not 100% sure it works though...

```
unitOfWork.BeginTransaction();
Category category =session.Load<Category>(id);
var productsDel = category.Products.Where(p => p.Categories.Count == 1);
productsDel.ForEach(p => session.Delete(p));
session.Delete(category);
unitOfWork.Commit();
```

*Other:*

I'm also thinking about adding mapping for your cross-ref tables. Then you should be able to configure mapping so it will delete only records from that cross-ref table. You will need to verify if there are products without references and delete them periodically. (some periodic clean-up code, like running some stored procedure). I know this solutions smells bad :) There are still triggers and other SQL Server stuff... not good solutions anyway, but solutions.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to remove the association between the two use `Cascade.SaveUpdate()`

Then just remove the entity from the collection and commit the transaction if you are using transactions if not you will need to do a Session.Flush

Comment: I don't understand. I thought saveUpdate would well resave it and I am not sure what you mean by remove the entity from the collection. I could have 1000's of products that need their reference to be remove when I delete the catergory so this seems to be what a cascade would be for then me having to do it myself.

Comment: I may have misunderstood your question but I can definitely see why `DeleteOrphan` and `AllDeleteOrphan` delete Product A in this instance. `SaveUpdate` will only delete the associations (the many to many table entries ... `product_category`) but will not delete `Product A`.  This is something you would have to handle manually when using this cascade setting.  I don't think there is a cascade that handles this (could be wrong though).

Comment: Hmm I will have to try it but I thought DeleteOrphan was exactly for this situation. I don't see it as to me Product A is not an orphan as it still has a relationship to something.